# updating the listview subitem text after an event

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have listview that may change text on event like shown :

```
    private void OnEvent(object sender, AutomateConnectionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (aListView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                Traitement(e);
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            Traitement(e); 
        }
    }


    private void Traitement(AutomateConnectionEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = aListView.FindItemWithText(e.idAutomate);
        if (e.notification.Equals("connect"))
        {
            aListView.Items[item.index].SubItems[5].Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();

            aListView.Items[item.index].SubItems[7].ForeColor = Color.Green;
            aListView.Items[item.index].SubItems[7].Text = "Connected";
            aListView.Items[item.index].SubItems[8].Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
```

It's rise no error and when follow this with breakpoint in visual studio it's run correctly but the listview won't change the text in the form

Comment: Most probably you're updating the different instance. Add `this.Show()` (assuming this refers to Form) in `Traitement` to see whether you get a new form shown.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create new `ListViewItem` object with new values and Update the old `ListeviewItem` with new ListViewItem object.